# in ASP.NET Core, is there any way to set up middleware from Program.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am building a support library for ASP.NET Core websites. I have a few pieces of middleware that need to be enabled, and they need to be added before any other middleware due what they do.

I can create an extension method on IWebHostBuilder to add services, likewise for configuring logging, but I don't see any way to add middleware in a programmatic way. Is there any way to do this? Looking at the source for WebHost/WebHostBuilder nothing jumped out.

---

Given the first comment, I may not have been clear enough. I know how to create middleware and use it. What I am trying to do is ensure that when the Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) method is called on Startup by the framework, my middleware is already in place. In a similar manner to being able to do ServiceConfiguration prior to Startup even being created. So an extension method like

```
public static IWebHostBuilder AddPayscaleHostingServices(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder, string serviceName)
{
    return webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(collection =>
    {
        collection.RegisterPayscaleHostingServices();
    }).ConfigureLogging(factory =>
    {

    });
}
```

gives me the ability to do some setup prior to the webHostBuilder.Build method, but I don't see anything similar for middleware/anything on IApplicationBuilder.

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: Please refer to this and do your own study first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

Comment: I know how to create middleware, and I know how to add middleware. What I don't know is how to ensure that my middleware is enabled prior to the Configure method is called on the Startup class. In a perfect world, I would have an opportunity to touch IApplicationBuilder before user code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a startup filter to achieve this. Startup filters allow you to configure middleware from a service resolved from the DI container.

Defining a startup filter is easy:

```
public class MyStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return app =>
        {
            // Configure middleware
            // ...

            // Call the next configure method
            next(app);
        };
    }
}
```

Always make sure to call `next(app)` or any other middleware **won't** be configured.

Now register the startup filter as a singleton implementation of `IStartupFilter` in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, MyStartupFilter>();
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, the name IStartupFilter got me thinking in the wrong direction. Now that I look at, and how it is used in WebHost, it makes sense. Not the name, but how I can use it.

Comment: Yeah, it confused me before too. However, it is a pretty neat and powerful way to configure middleware.