# Set dummy IP address in integration test with Asp.Net Core TestServer

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a C# Asp.Net Core (1.x) project, implementing a web REST API, and its related integration test project, where before any test there's a setup similar to:

```cs
// ...

IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder = GetWebHostBuilderSimilarToRealOne()
    .UseStartup<MyTestStartup>();

TestServer server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
server.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");

HttpClient client = server.CreateClient();

// ...
```

During tests, the `client` is used to send HTTP requests to web API (the system under test) and retrieve responses.

Within actual system under test there's some component extracting sender IP address from each request, as in:

```cs
HttpContext httpContext = ReceiveHttpContextDuringAuthentication();

// edge cases omitted for brevity
string remoteIpAddress = httpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString()
```

Now during integration tests this bit of code fails to find an IP address, as `RemoteIpAddress` is always null.

Is there a way to set that to some known value from within test code? I searched here on SO but could not find anything similar. TA

Comment: Show `ReceiveHttpContextDuringAuthentication()`

Comment: That is *just* a fictional function to represent what's going on. In actual code, IP address is extracted within an extension point provided by the authentication framework ([ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server)). That framework passes the current request `HttpContext` as one of the inputs to the extension point.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can write middleware to set custom IP Address since this property is writable:

```cs
public class FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IPAddress fakeIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.168.1.32");

    public FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress = fakeIpAddress;

        await this.next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Then you can create `StartupStub` class like this:

```cs
public class StartupStub : Startup
{
    public StartupStub(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware>();
        base.Configure(app, env);
    }
}
```

And use it to create a `TestServer`:

```cs
new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<StartupStub>());
```

Comment: it looks like that could be the missing part. Thanks for example, I'll try it but yes, it looks quite promising

Comment: Did you get this working with dotnet core 2.x, too? Looks like "Configure" can't be overridden any more in 2.x.

Comment: @Ralf did you mark `Configure` as `virtual` in your `Startup` class?

Comment: @PavelAgarkov your solution is hardcoding the IP in the Middleware, that means that the same IP address will be used for all integration tests. Is there also a way to declare the IP to be used individually for each test case (e.g. while creating the HttpRequest), so that various test scenarios (with various IP addresses) can be taken into account?

Comment: @Dario, sure, you can use ConfigureTestServices to register some service that will be injected into FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware and used to obtain current ip address. This way you can specify different ip addresses right before using the client.

Answer (score 22):

As per this answer [in ASP.NET Core, is there any way to set up middleware from Program.cs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603568/in-asp-net-core-is-there-any-way-to-set-up-middleware-from-program-cs)

It's also possible to configure the middleware from ConfigureServices, which allows you to create a custom WebApplicationFactory without the need for a StartupStub class:

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder<Startup>(new string[0])
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, CustomStartupFilter>();
            });
    }
}


public class CustomStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return app =>
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware>();
            next(app);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It's impossible to configure additional middleware directly through `WebApplicationFactory` without inheriting a new Startup class (which has its own downsides), but this approach works really well.

Comment: For people using .NET 5 or Core 3.x, the .ConfigureServices call should be put in ```protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)``` instead of ```CreateWebHostBuilder```

Comment: Using this approach in ASP.NET Core 3.x or higher? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69191951/798781).

Answer (score 2):

Using WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder can mess up with your app configuration.

And there's no need to change Product code just to accommodate for testing, unless absolutely necessary.

The simplest way to add your own middleware, without overriding Startup class methods, is to add the middleware through a `IStartupFilter‍` as suggested by Elliott's answer.

But instead of using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`, just use

```
base.CreateWebHostBuilder().ConfigureServices...

    public class CustomWAF : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
        {
            return base.CreateWebHostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, CustomStartupFilter>();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer even if it's relatively an old one. At the moment I'm far away from a similar project, let's see what happens with new projects.

Answer (score 2):

Does your Web app call [IApplicationBuilder.UseForwardedHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.forwardedheadersextensions.useforwardedheaders)?

```csharp
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new() {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor
});
```

If so, then you can simply add the `X-Forwarded-For` header to your test HTTP requests:

```csharp
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        base.ConfigureClient(client);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Forwarded-For", "192.168.0.1");
    }
}
```

No need to write any test-only middleware!

Comment: I was not aware of this extension, I don't think that application used them at the time, but it's good to know though

Answer (score 1):

I used [Elliott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54943385/798781) within an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project. However, updating to ASP.NET 5.0, I had to replace the override of `CreateWebHostBuilder` with the below override of `CreateHostBuilder`:

```cs
protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    return Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, CustomStartupFilter>();
        });
}
```