# WebApplicationFactory Set IP Address at startup

Tags: c#, .net-core

Hitting a snag here, we have an IP Witelist blocker on our API.
The WebApplicationFactory when it starts has 'null' for the IPAddress, and I can't see how to set it.

I've been googling around and trying different ideas, but so far nothing has worked.

Des anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to determine the current user's IP?

Comment: Hey, if you haven't found it by now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54943385/2168677 is actually what we are using to set the IP address to any value you'd like

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution for this problem from combining answers from [Set dummy IP address in integration test with Asp.Net Core TestServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244283/set-dummy-ip-address-in-integration-test-with-asp-net-core-testserver/54943385#54943385)

The benefit of this solution is that you do not need to inherit from `WebApplicationFactory`

## Setup

```
_factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
                
        services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, CustomStartupFilter>();
    });
});
```

### Helper Classes

I used static fields and methods to make it possible to change the IPs while in test. You could also just hardcode them like in the commented out code

```
public class CustomStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return app =>
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware>();
            next(app);
        };
    }
}

public class FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    //private readonly IPAddress fakeIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.168.1.32");
    private static IPAddress fakeIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.168.1.32");

    public static void RandomizeIp()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        random.NextBytes(bytes);
        fakeIpAddress = new IPAddress(bytes);
    }

    public FakeRemoteIpAddressMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress = fakeIpAddress;

        await this.next(httpContext);
    }
}
```